# Does Impersonation work in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, impersonation

I am having issues with Impersonation in an ASP.NET MVC application, and just want to check if there are any known issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've used it before successfully in one of my projects, no issues.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, works well. There is no any known issues with "impersonation" in ASP.NET MVC.